# Websockets stream-adventure ending stream

Tags: node.js, stream, websocket

I am working on the Websockets challenge for stream-adventure. There is a known bug in the adventure and anything passes, but I know my first solution isn't correct, and I'm wondering if someone can help explain why not.

Here is the prompt:

In this adventure, write some browser code that uses the websocket-stream module
to print the string "hello\n".

Your solution file will be compiled with browserify and the verify script will
prompt you to open `http://localhost:8000` in a browser to verify your solution.

To open a stream with websocket-stream on localhost:8000, just write:

```
var ws = require('websocket-stream');
var stream = ws('ws://localhost:8000');
```

Then write the string "hello\n" to the stream and end the stream.

Here is my original solution. I know it isn't correct because it doesn't end the stream. Can someone clarify if I was even on the right path? Is it correct to create a readable stream, or should it be writeable?

```
var ws = require('websocket-stream');
var stream = ws('ws://localhost:8000');
var fs = require('fs');

var str = 'hello\n';

fs.createReadStream(str).pipe(stream);
```

Here is the correct answer:

```
var ws = require('websocket-stream');
var stream = ws('ws://localhost:8000');
stream.end('hello\n');
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question in the question itself? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Sorry, the correct answer at the end is just the one I found online. I am asking about my initial attempt - is it on the right path? Am I missing a step? If it doesn't solve the problem, what DOES it do?

Comment: You were trying to read from a file named "hello\n". [fs.createReadStream](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)